# CSS Stylesheet Not Reflecting changes

Tags: css

I am using external `stylesheet` for styling my `default.aspx` page , i am using master page in my project.I am referring to the `stylesheet` in the `master` page.
My problem is , i have many `dropdowns` and `textboxes` on my `form` , i am using both `classes` and `id's` for each control.When i use `class` for a particular control in `stylesheet` changes are reflected ,, however when i use id for `styling` , changes are not reflected.Controls remain as they were.This must  be something really obvious that i may be missing.I am using '.' and '#' for `class` and `id` respectively.Any help is much appreciated.
Here is my `default.css` file

```
.textbox ,.dropdown,.checkdate1,.checkdate2,.NumZero,.NumLenZero,.NumDecTwo {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.textbox,.checkdate1,.checkdate2,.NumZero,.NumLenZero,.NumDecTwo { 
    border:1px solid gray;
}

#disabled {
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color:White;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid gray;
}

#drpCustType,#drpGender,#drpCountry,#drpMaritalStatus,#drpCorrespAdd,#drpEducation,#drpOccupation {
    width:130px;
}

#drpResCity,#drpOffCity,#drpNativeCity {
    width:160px;
}

#drpInitial,#drpReligion {
    width:100px;
}

#drpBranchName,#drpResState,#drpOffState,#drpNativeState {
    width:200px;
}

#drpIdentification {
    width:220px;
}

#drpAddressProof {
    width:253px;
}

#txtResAdd,#txtOffAdd,#txtNativeAdd {
    width:350px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#txtCustNo {
    margin-left:2px;
}

#txtBirthDate {
    margin-left:8px;
}

#drpIdentification {
    margin-left:6px;
}

#drpAddressProof{margin-left:-3px;}
#txtIDExpiryDate{margin-left:14px;}
#txtAddExpiryDate{margin-left:14px;}
#drpResCity,#drpOffCity,#drpNativeCity{margin-left:16px;}
#txtIDIssuedAt{margin-left:8px;}
#txtIDIssueDate{margin-left:1px;}
#drpResState,#drpOffState,#drpNativeState{margin-left:0px;}

#cmdSubmit{margin-left:50%;margin-top:10px;width:80px;height:30px;}

.date,.num{display:none;color:red;font-weight:bold;margin-left:3px;}
/*Custom validator Styling*/
#opendate,#reqdopendate,#birthdate,#restelno,#resmobno,#offtelno,#offmobno,#nativetelno,#nativemobno,#telno,#mobno,#monthincome,#idexpirydate,#addexpirydate,#idissuedate,#addissuedate{color:Red;font-weight:bold;margin-left:3px;}

#birthdate1,#resmobno1,#offmobno1,#nativemobno1,#mobno1,#idissuedate1,#addissuedate1{color:Red;font-weight:bold;margin-left:-7px;}

#easyTooltip {
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #195fa4;
    background:#195fa4 url(bg.gif) repeat-x;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    color:#fff;
}

#Validation {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: you should probably post a sample of your html and css

Comment: Source Code or a place to view the problem would be great, so we can help you. Without that, we can't offer much help.

Comment: could be an issue of specificity http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ read up on it

Comment: Maybe your form controls have no `id`, and have `name` only. `id` and `name` are different things. For more clarity on your issue, it makes sense that you show us live example (with jsfiddle.net for example).

Comment: make sure you are using correct ids names in css...also make sure that those ids are applied to the fields.

Comment: @MaratTanalin ,,, my controls have ids set properly ,,,, wondering what could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a local cache issue? trying clearing you browser cache and reloading page

failing that your id's are wrong. Or you are trying to use it to style something that isn't applicable (margin-top/bottom on an inline element for example)